# Ranorex mobile automation to click on a system prompt e.g. Wi-Fi in iOS

Tags: ios, testing, mobile, automation, ranorex

We have a Ranorex mobile app automation for an iOS native app that gets stuck trying provision Wi-Fi. It can't seem to get past a system security prompt asking the user to confirm switching Wi-Fi access point.

Tried clicking by specifying the button by its visible text label, but the click fails. Unsure if the problem is automation focus remains in-app, or that the system prompt has magic identifiers.

Is this a known limitation of Ranorex in iOS? Or is there a special way to specify the locator id of a system prompt?